# IIS 7.5 HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized - Wierd

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

I have just set up a windows 2008 server and installed IIS on it.
The thing is while one web page working fine (2014.flptr.com) the other (www.flptr.com) is throwing above error. I triple checked they have same settings and they point to the same folder on the computer.

How come this may happen??

Any info appreciated!

THanks!

Comment: Please try this link http://serverfault.com/questions/341978/troubleshooting-windows-authentication-problems-no-challenge-in-iis-7-5

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the applicationHost.config file, replaced security information with the website's that is working. I guess it had something to do with IUSR account password.

THanks!